Kotlin KSP: How to generate aggregating output files
I have project with several KSP processors and Dagger2 on kapt. Recently I tried to migrate Dagger to KSP and found several issues in our KSP processors with aggregating output. These issues make me think about how it should work in KSP in general.
Please, help me understand correct strategy for file generation in KSP.
I have following requirements:

All classes annotated with @AutoModule should be collected in GeneratedModule class, created by AutoModuleProcessor (aggregating output)
Classes annotated with @GenerateAutoModule should generate another class with @AutoModule annotation (created by GenerateAutoModuleProcessor)
Class annotated with @Component should generate Generated${ClassName} by ComponentProcessor:
@Component annotation has GeneratedModule in argument (GeneratedModule not exists before AutoModuleProcessor finishes)
All classes listed in @Component argument must be valid for successful generation by ComponentProcessor.

Code example:
class ExistingModule

@AutoModule
class SimpleAutoModule

@GenerateAutoModule
class ComplexAutoModule

@Component(
    // GeneratedModule not exists before AutoModuleProcessor execution
    [ExistingModule::class, GeneratedModule::class]
)
interface SourceComponent

Generated code should be following:
@AutoModule
class GeneratedComplexAutoModule

@Module(
    [
        com.example.SimpleAutoModule::class,
        com.example.GeneratedComplexAutoModule::class
    ]
)
class GeneratedModule

class GeneratedSourceComponent

Example project can be found here: https://github.com/bomiyr/ksp-playground
Current setup require AutoModuleProcessor run in several rounds and I cannot understand how to generate file properly:

If I generate file after every round, I get FileAlreadyExistsException.
If I move file generation into finish(), GeneratedSourceComponent cannot be generated, because GeneratedModule cannot be resolved at the moment of ComponentProcessor execution.
If I try to postpone symbols processing to the next round, I don't have any meaningful condition to stop processing and finally generate the file.

The only solution I get is to hardcode rounds count in AutoModuleProcessor to 2, but this does not seem very reliable:
        if (rounds == 2) {
            generateFile()
        }

So what is the correct way to handle such cases?
